# New user to ReactJS, can I access with regular javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I develop e-learning courses with Articulate Storyline, which now seems to be using ReactJS under the hood for rendering their courses. This has thrown a monkey-wrench into the works for many of us that used regular javascript to control course variables in the previous versions of the software.

I've done some reading up on ReactJS, so I have a cursory understanding of it. One simple thing I'm trying to accomplish, is to control the volume in my course with custom code that I've written. The courses have a volume slider already, but I can't figure out how the volume is controlled with ReactJS.

Here's a very simple course file that plays a video with sound (thunder) when loaded. You can see the player's default volume control below the video. I've been looking through the source code and trying different things in Chrome's developer tools for 2 days now, but I've not made any progress. Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can access this (volume) and other variables?

http://storyline.host22.com/MuteTest/story_html5.html

Comment: A change in the way you would use the service should be reflected in a change to their API documentation. Has it been updated?

Comment: Articulate does not officially support ANY javascript interaction with their built-in variables. The best they have done is provide this very short document with some examples of how to get and set javascript variables that we the users ourselves have created: https://articulate.com/support/article/Storyline-3-JavaScript-Best-Practices-and-Examples  In the past, some have discovered some of the built-in variables to extend capabilities, but I'm not sure why the developer doesn't just publish a list that we could access. Is there no way to easily tell which variables are in use?